# How can I change bucket or prefix when writing to Google Cloud Storage from Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In a streaming dataflow pipeline, how can I dynamically change the bucket or the prefix of data I write to cloud storage?

For example, I would like to store data to text or avro files on GCS, but with a prefix that includes the processing hour.

**Update:** The question is invalid because there simply is no sink you can use in streaming dataflow that writes to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Streaming Dataflow doesn't have a built-in GCS sink; what are you currently using to do the write?

Comment: You are right, there is no way of doing streaming GCS write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataflow currently does not allow GCS sinks in streaming mode.